# Debug Assertion failed with msvc2019 and qt 6.1, refered a nonexist file

Tags: c++

When I debug my application I got a Debug Assertion Failed output,

**Debug Assertion Failed!
Program: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVCP140D.dll
File: D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\vector
Line: 73
Expression: vector iterator not dereferencable
For information on how your program can cause an assertion
failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.
(Press Retry to debug the application)**

There are no visual studio 2015 installed in my D Drive, so the targeted file does not exist, how can I fix this?

plus:
Thanks for all of your replies, my problem was solved, I tried serveral days to work around this. Still I am not sure why this happened, my guess is using some improper libraries.

Regards

Comment: The assertion may originate in a file you don't have available, but the root cause is much more likely to be in your code. Create a debug build, and run in a debugger to catch the crash, and locate when and where in *your* code it happens. Also examine all involved variables and check their values.

Comment: When you get the assert, break into the debugger (press retry), open the stack frame window and unwind the frames until you find your code.  Re why you get references to drive D: and another version of MSVC - the code is using a library built with this version; this is a concern as code may not be compatible if built with different versions.  MS has a document re ABI stability and I will try and find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system installed file `C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVCP140D.dll` was compiled with the `vector` included on a `D:` drive

So the failure is within the DLL, and not on your drive.  I believe the file is a support file for `C++` code for Visual Studio 2015, and was built by the vendor (Microsoft), on 'D:'

The D at the end MSVCP140**D** says it is a debug binary.  This should not be deployed, unless it is a developer machine with VS2015 installed.

If that is the case, the `vector` error is readable, by looking on your machine.

If you don't have VS2015 installed, then unfortunately your code has fallen foul of people releasing debug code.

Open the code in a debugger, and check if the failure is caused by a fault in the data that is being provided by anything you control (parameters to functions), assuming you have vs2015, ask VS to open vector from your install.